# Can you apply conditional formatting in Logi Reports?

Tags: xml

In a website Logi Report, I have an .lgx file where two table columns are defined. These are a "Previous Value" and a "New Value", and their purpose is to display the old value and the new value when one of several fields has been changed in a given record. See the xml below:

```
<DataTableColumn ID="colchange_field_type" Header="Updated Field Type">
     <Label ID="lblchange_field_type" Caption="@Data.changeFieldType~" />
     <DataColumnSort DataColumn="change_field_type" />
</DataTableColumn>
<DataTableColumn ID="colprevious_value" Header="Previous Value" Class="ThemeAlignRight">
     <Label ID="lblprevious_value" Caption="@Data.previousValue~" Format="General Number" />
     <DataColumnSort DataColumn="previous_value" />
</DataTableColumn>
<DataTableColumn ID="colcurrent_value" Header="Current Value" Class="ThemeAlignRight">
     <Label ID="lblcurrent_value" Caption="@Data.currentValue~" Format="General Number" />
     <DataColumnSort DataColumn="current_value" />
</DataTableColumn>
```

As can be seen, they both have the "format" attribute set to "General Number". The problem is that with each row, @Data.previousValue~ and @Data.currentValue~ can be one of several datatypes (date, currency, text, general number, or others).

Is there some way to conditionally set the format attribute, based on the @Data.changeFieldType~? Right now, whenever the value is a date, on browser screen it's displaying in the cell as misspelled text - "General Nu0ber".

I've seen a page in the Logi documentation that talks about the "ConditionalClass" element, but applying a CSS class isn't really what I'm looking to do here.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this question was asked 6 months ago, but on the chance someone else has a similar question: You can definitely use any of the `@Local`, `@Request`, or other `@Data` tokens to populate `Format` dynamically.

Using your provided example, if your DataLayer looks like this:

```
+-----------------+---------------+--------------+
| changeFieldType | previousValue | currentValue |
+------------------------------------------------+
|    Short Date   |   2020-04-14  |  2020-10-13  |
+------------------------------------------------+
| ###,###,##0.00  |     12000     |     24000    |
+-----------------+---------------+--------------+
```

Then your code will be as follows:

```
<DataTableColumn ID="colprevious_value" Header="Previous Value" Class="ThemeAlignRight">
     <Label ID="lblprevious_value" Caption="@Data.previousValue~" Format="@Data.changeFieldType~" />
     <DataColumnSort DataColumn="previous_value" />
</DataTableColumn>
<DataTableColumn ID="colcurrent_value" Header="Current Value" Class="ThemeAlignRight">
     <Label ID="lblcurrent_value" Caption="@Data.currentValue~" Format="@Data.changeFieldType~" />
     <DataColumnSort DataColumn="current_value" />
</DataTableColumn>
```

And your results will be:

```
+-------------------------------+
| Previous Value|  Current Value|
+-------------------------------+
|      4/14/2020|     10/13/2020|
+-------------------------------+
|      12,000.00|      24,000.00|
+-------------------------------+
```